# Get Color Shade with PHP

Tags: php, colors, hex

I want to get brighter hex colour shade output from a given hex value with PHP. For example, I give the colour `#cc6699` as input, and I want `#ee88aa` as the output colour. How would I go about doing this in PHP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to convert the color to RGB, make the additions, and convert back:

```
// Convert string to 3 decimal values (0-255)
$rgb = array_map('hexdec', str_split("cc6699", 2));

// Modify color
$rgb[0] += 34;
$rgb[1] += 34;
$rgb[2] += 17;

// Convert back
$result = implode('', array_map('dechex', $rgb));

echo $result;
```

[See it in action here](http://ideone.com/rBlfJ).

Comment: @Jon Thanks very much your solution is well and i will do this

Comment: @Jon Jon 1 thing i can not understand in third value difference $rgb[2] += 17; please clear me

Comment: @jon Jon my input value is with # from my database and i need output value also with # hash for using in my css and i can not like to change values from database and my structure there is 32+ values saved with colorpicker.js

Comment: @Anjum: `34 == 0x22` and `17 = 0x11`. `0xcc + 0x22` => `0xcc`,  `0x66 + 0x22` => `0x88`, `0x99c + 0x11` => `0xaa`. All together: `#cc6699 => #ee88aa`.

Comment: @Jon oh sorry i am understand

Comment: @JamWaffles Thank JamWaffles for editing  my question my english is not very good thanks

Comment: @jon Jon my input value is with # from my database and i need output value also with # hash for using in my css and i can not like to change values from database and my structure there is 32+ values saved with colorpicker.js

Comment: @Anjum: Use `str_replace` to remove the "#" and add it with `"#".$result`. It's really simple.

Answer (score 1):

1. split the color in three elements: cc, 66, 99
2. Convert it to decimal with http://php.net/manual/de/function.hexdec.php
3. Increment three decimal values
4. Convert decimal to hex again
5. put the three elements together

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to convert the [RGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) to [HSL or HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) (just search google for [php converter hsl/hsv](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=php+converter+rgb+to+hsl+OR+hsv)).

Then you can play with the 'lightness' or 'value' values of the colorspace.

Afterwards convert it back to RGB colorspace.